# Получить значение радиокнопки

Tags: html, css

Есть такая верстка

```
<div class="radio_buttons">
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio1" checked />
                        <label for="radio1">Daily</label>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input  type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio4" />
                        <label for="radio4">Weekly</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio2" />
                        <label for="radio2">Twice a week</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio3" />
                        <label for="radio3">Three times a week</label>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

4 радионкнопки. Когда получаю значение то получаю `[type_of_cleaning] => on`  а как получить значение Daily, Weekly, Twice a week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте `value` для инпутов:

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio_buttons">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio1" checked value="daily" />
    <label for="radio1">Daily</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio4" value="weekly" />
    <label for="radio4">Weekly</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio2" value="twice a week" />
    <label for="radio2">Twice a week</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="type_of_cleaning" id="radio3" value="hree times a week" />
    <label for="radio3">Three times a week</label>
  </div>

</div>
```